# How to select from multiple MySQL columns using wildcards and spaces?

Tags: mysql

I have a typeahead select box for finding users in a database. Frequently there are meny users with the same first name & different last names. 
A person searching for a user would generally type in: "John doe".

The problem with this is that the typeahead will start getting all the John users but then return no results when the space is typed in. 
"WHY" this is happening is obvious, user first names are trimmed & anything with a space will not match ~ let alone with another character following that, first & last names are stored in separate columns.

Here is the query as it stands:

```
SELECT Entities.* FROM `Entities` 
WHERE `Entities`.`first_name` LIKE '%john doe%' 
OR `Entities`.`last_name` LIKE '%john doe %'
```

How can I re-write this query so that the results would be:

- all users whose first name is john
- ignore any amount of spaces
- AND where last name is doe

when a user types in"john doe" in the search control

(Keeping in mind that the search control is ONE text type field)

Comment: what is your server side technology beside mysql? Conceptually, I would split the input by space characters. Trim each of the input pieces, and search for each of the result words in fields of your database. It would also work for spanish names consisting in more than 2 pieces, which is nice.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first name like `john` and the last name like `doe`, then try something like:

```
where concat(Entities`.`first_name`, ' ', `Entities`.`last_name`) like '%john% doe%'
```

If you want do do this based on a search string, then something like:

```
where concat(`Entities`.`first_name`, ' ', `Entities`.`last_name`) like
          concat('%', replace('john doe', ' ', '%'), '%')
```

Or, use full text search.

Comment: thanks - this seems to be just what I am looking for.